# Maven—read credentials from settings.xml in pom

Tags: maven, pom.xml

is it possible to read server credentials from the settings.xml within a pom.xml? I would like to download files as described [here](http://evgeny-goldin.com/wiki/Copy-maven-plugin#Downloading_files%3a_HTTP.2C_SCP.2C_FTP), but avoid to put the credentials in version control.

Thanks in ahead!

Comment: Why not using [maven-dependency-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) or [wagon-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/wagon-maven-plugin/) which will use credentials from settings.xml file.

Comment: maven wagon is very slow, I want to download a whole bunch of files so the wagon keeps me waiting too long.

Comment: Have you tried to use the [download](http://mojo.codehaus.org/wagon-maven-plugin/download-mojo.html) goal? And what does slow mean in comparsion to what ?

Comment: I tried the download goal with my local ftp server and it left me waiting telling me: »scanning remote filesystem«, until I just aborted it. I am trying to download about 30MB of files, many small files…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is profile based properties like shown below:

```
<profile>
    <id>jira</id>
    <properties>
        <jiraUser>user</jiraUser>
        <jiraPassword>password</jiraPassword>
    </properties>
</profile>
```

You may reference these with `${jiraUser}` and `{jiraPassword}` in your POM. Make sure to activate the profile in your `settings.xml`.

Comment: that seems to be the only way… It is not what I had in mind, but that is maven…

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by settings.xml within a pom.xml (Sorry admin for Posting this in Answers instead of comments, since I cant add comments I am doing this in Answers)

Comment: Commenting is a privilege ;-)

Comment: I mean: There is the ~/.m2/settings.xml used by maven to store credentials for servers. This file is independent from each pom.xml which is normally managed by a version control system. To prevent passwords from being distributed in teams.